# Can i print image and text view data by formatting to Bluetooth printer without using SDK

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

when I am trying to print image and text view data by formatting  to Bluetooth printer ,plain data can print successfully  but images are not available to print  and i am not clear how to format text and print these formatted data.

Comment: You might have better luck if you provide the specifics of what you're working with and exactly how the problem is manifesting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll probably need to use some sort of sdk. API 19+ has methods to work with printers. See here: http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html